# Inside a deserialize method, how can I find the parent of the field (token) that is currently getting deserialized?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Inside a `JsonDeserializer#deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctx)` method, how can I find the parent of the field (token) that is currently getting deserialized?

By parent, I mean the closest token in the ancestry of the current field that is of type `START_OBJECT`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you need to know the type of the parent?

Comment: I want to know the name of the parent field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't; while information is being used by parent deserializer, it is not being passed or maintained, to minimize overhead.